# LINQ Updating Sort Order to nearest possible value

Tags: c#, .net, database, linq, lambda

I have a table with items that are displayed by their SortOrder. The SortOrders are not incremented very well, with values skipping anywhere from 1-100. What I want to do is flip-flop the SortOrder values of two items that are closest together, without necessarily knowing *how* close together they are. For example:

```
ItemX.SortOrder = 5;
ItemY.SortOrder = 26;
```

Assume no items have a sort order between 5-26.

My code needs to switch this to:

```
ItemX.SortOrder = 26;
ItemY.SortOrder = 5;
```

For some reason, my code is switching SortOrders with random items, such that:

```
ItemX.SortOrder = 5;
ItemY.SortOrder = 26;
ItemZ.SortOrder = 34;
```

Becomes:

```
ItemX.SortOrder = 34;
ItemY.SortOrder = 26;
ItemZ.SortOrder = 5;
```

I think its because the results of my query aren't ordered the way I am picturing them. Here is my query code. If anything else is needed, just let me know.

```
itemToSwitch = DataSource.Items.Where(item => item.SortOrder > currentItem.SortOrder).First();
int? next = itemToSwitch.SortOrder;
int? previous = currentItem.SortOrder;
currentItem.SortOrder = next;
itemToSwitch.SortOrder = previous;
```

Sorry if my question is difficult to read or jumbled. I'm trying to be as clear as possible.

Comment: you need to post the whole function. This is just a query snippet that does what it sais. However, there is zero flip-flopping going on.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this, out of curiosity? What's your goal?

Comment: I'm trying to make it so users can reorder the results from a gridview by clicking on up or down arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suspecting you actually want:

```
 var sorted = DataSource.Items.OrderBy(item => item.SortOrder);
```

If you're reusing it, a `.ToList()` might help

Comment: Glad it helped. It was a lucky guess; next time, like others mentioned, try to describe the problem first, and then where you're stuck. Something like 'I want the user to be able to define the sort order for the list shown'. In actuality, I don't think you need a sort while doing that. But when saving, you'd probably want to use the list index as the SortOrder key to persist :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do not use:

```
var greatesItem = DataSource.Items.OrderBy(item => item.SortOrder).Fisrt();
var smallestItem = DataSource.Items.OrderBy(item => item.SortOrder).Last();

var tempOrder = greatesItem.SortOrder;
greatesItem.SortOrder = smallestItem.SortOrder;
smallestItem.SortOrder = tempOrder;
```

Then you submit the modification to the database. (I suggest you to do a function with that).

Comment: I'm not trying to switch the first and last items though, just the next item sequentially.

Comment: In the description it was not clear if the list contains more thant 2 items. Sorry for the assuption.